macOS Sonoma is creating a Link-Local IP on a separate interface
I’m running macOS Sonoma 14.5 on an M1 MacBook Pro. I recently discovered it was sending out requests on 1900/UDP (Bonjour) to 239.255.255.250 (Multicast) via Link-Local IP (169.254.134.196) over WiFi on a separate interface (en12) than my WiFi adapter (en0).
What is causing this? No other Macs on my LAN seem to be doing this. How can I shut it off?

How did you determine that's Bonjour? The port number looks like UPnP's SSDP (Microsoft's "what if Bonjour but WinXP"), entirely unlike what mDNS uses.
